# How to map m:n relation to slice field?

Tags: sql, go, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I have a struct `Person`:

```
type Person struct {
    Id     int64
    Name   string
    Colors []string
}
```

which should get its data from a `person` table:

```
id | name
---------
1  | Joe
2  | Moe
```

and a `person_color` table:

```
person_id | color
-----------------
1         | black
1         | blue
2         | green
```

Via `SELECT p.id, p.name, pc.color FROM person AS p INNER JOIN person_color AS pc ON pc.person_id = p.id` I merge both tables to:

```
id | name | color
-----------------
1  | Joe  | black
1  | Joe  | blue
2  | Moe  | green
```

At the moment the only thing I could think of would be to manually map colors while iterating over `rows.Next()` (NOTE: *just dummy code*):

```
ps := make([]People, 0)

rows, err := db.Query("SELECT ...")

for rows.Next() {
    var p Person

    err := rows.Scan(&p.Id, &p.Name, &p.Color[0])

    exists := false

    for _, ps := range ps {
        if ps.Id == p {
            exists = true

            ps.Color = append(ps.Color, p.Color)
        }
    }

    if !exists {
        ps = append(ps, p)
    }
}
```

Though this would work this is quite annoying as mapping to a slice field is a common operation.

**Is there any way to make the above generic on all slice fields with [sql](http://godoc.org/database/sql) or [sqlx](http://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx)?**

Comment: One more generic way is to split the query.  Query the names and create `People` objects with empty `Colors`.  Then query all colors for all names, and add them to the People.  This approach scales to multiple foreign keys, or "slice fields" as you call them :)

Comment: @Andomar hmm I think using another query would not solve this problem as you still need to reduce the returned rows somehow. At the moment I think the best we could do is a `Peoples` type which has a `Reduce()` method which merges all `People` with same `People.Id`. But still wondering that there is so few reaction on this - doesn't seem to exotic for me :)

Comment: Yeah, this is a [very common problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch).  As an old programmer, my advise is not to spend too much time on moving data from tables to objects.  The problem is not worth points by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd almost certainly approach this from the SQL side.  In PostgreSQL you can use the [array_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-aggregate.html) to get array types back, which given the proper Scanner implementation should be resistant to weird data values:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, pc.color FROM 
       person AS p INNER JOIN 
       array_agg(person_color) AS pc 
    ON
       pc.person_id = p.id
    GROUP BY p.id;
```

This would return:

```
 id | name |  array_agg
----+------+--------------
  1 | Joe  | {black,blue}
  2 | Moe  | {green}
```

It's up to you to create a Go type like `type pgarraystring []string` and [implement Scanner](http://jmoiron.net/blog/built-in-interfaces), though it's possible I will add some of these types for PostgreSQL someday soon in the `github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/types` package.

In MySQL or SQLite, you're going to lack array types, but you can use `GROUP_CONCAT`[1] to achieve similar results.  In other databases, there should be a similar concat aggregate which works with the text representation.

There are a few reasons for going this route.  You're using an SQL database for a reason; it should be able to return you the data you want in the desired format;  unless it's really going to be a problem and you've measured it, fall back on it, that's its strength as a datastore.  It also reduces the amount of data being sent back over the wire and the number of fetches being done by the cursor, so in general it should behave better.

[1] Sorry, I can't post a link to `GROUP_CONCAT` because I don't have any StackOverflow reputation, but you should be able to google it.

Comment: For MySQL `SELECT p.id, p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(pc.color) AS color FROM person AS p INNER JOIN person_color AS pc ON pc.person_id = p.id GROUP BY p.id` works (important is the `GROUP BY p.id` in the end). The scanner would then just need a simple type switch with `strings.Split("black,blue", ",")` to use.

Comment: Really thanks a lot for this answer. It makes handling arrays of data in SQL very easy and may be very useful outside of Go world too :)

Comment: For PostgresSQL, the pq.StringArray type is an implementation of the sql.Scanner interface that would work for this. This works great with sqlx.

Answer (score 0):

I was expecting the code to look more like this.

```
// Assuming the context is in a function that can return _error_.
ps := make(map[int64]Person)

rows, err := db.Query("SELECT ...")

for rows.Next() {
    var id int64
    var name string
    var color string
    err := rows.Scan(&id, &name, &color)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    p, ok := ps[id]
    if !ok {
        p.Id = id
        p.Name = name
    }
    p.Colors = append(p.Colors, color)
    ps[id] = p
}
```

The code you have now is potentially expensive because the original code is iterating across all the people, for each row in the joined table.  Rather than do the manual scan, you can you can quickly jump to the right entry by means of the mapping.

Also, the original code fails to save the modified person back into the slice if it already exists.  Remember, you're working with *Person*, not **Person*.  If you do work with *Person, the code above can be refined to:

```
// Assuming the context is in a function that can return _error_.
ps := make(map[int64]*Person)

rows, err := db.Query("SELECT ...")

for rows.Next() {
    var id int64
    var name string
    var color string
    err := rows.Scan(&id, &name, &color)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    p, ok := ps[id]
    if !ok {
        p := &Person{id, name, []string{color}}
        ps[id] = p
        continue
    }
    p.Colors = append(p.Colors, color)
}
```